# "Branching" topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand why in general relativity we require spacetime to be a Hausdorff space. (I am a physics student not a mathematics student by the way.)

The 'handwavy' reason that is usually given is that non Hausdorff spaces can have "branching", which we do not want to have for spacetime. As an example of what I mean by branching consider two real lines with standard topology, let us call them $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O}_{std})$ and $(\mathbb{R}',\mathcal{O}'_{std})$.  If I now 'glue' the lines together for $x \in (-\infty,0)$ and $x' \in (-\infty', 0')$ by identifying the points with equal negative values, I get a 'Y shaped' space. This will clearly violate the Hausdorff condition, since $0$ and $0'$ are two points that are disitinct but have no disjoint neighborhoods. This seems clear, even intuitive.

What I do not understand is if the Hausdorff condition prevents this kind of branching from happening altogether. The previous example was an example of a non-Hausdorff space with branching. On the other hand, if a glue together $x \in (-\infty,0]$ and $x' \in (-\infty', 0']$ I can no longer pick distinct points which do not have disjoint neighborhoods, so this seems to be a Hausdorff space, on the other hand it has what I naively called 'branching'. What did I do wrong?

(One thing I can think of is that if I do the gluing this way I no longer get a topological space, but I do not see which open axiom gets violated.)

Comment: After your first gluing, $0$ and $0'$ become one and the same point, hence are no  longer distinct.  The problem with the glued object is not that it fails to be Hausdorff, but that it fails to be a manifold (see Arnol'd's "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" or his "Ordinary differential equations").

The Hausdorff property allows to construct a sufficiently rich family of continuous functions to approximate the desired functions.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn's_lemma

Comment: What you did is fine and does indeed produce a Hausdorff space; it just isn't one that branches in the intended sense of the word. When you reach $0$, you simply have a choice of paths. In the first space you travel to the right through the negative numbers and suddenly find yourself in two places at once, so to speak, $0$ and $0'$.

Comment: To expand on that a little, a continuous change — travelling towards the right on the negative axis — has an indeterminate limit or, if you prefer, two limits: you can end up at $0$ or at $0'$ (or perhaps both). This is still very handwavy — I’m no physicist — but it does, I think, explain the intuition a little further.

Comment: @avs: Whether it’s a manifold depends on one’s definitions. For me it’s a standard example of a non-Hausdorff manifold; others incorporate Hausdorffness in their definition of manifold.

Comment: Let me try to clarify:

Comment: I believe that:
1) when I do not glue the zeros I get a non-Haussdorf space
2) when I glue the zeros I do get a Hausdorff space.
In both cases I get a completely fine topological space, it is also straightforward to give an atlas and make these into manifolds.

Now, you say that case 1) is branching, while case 2) does not branch. So I get the feeling that by "branching" what one means is that "there are no problems with convergence", so in case 2) the limits of sequences are unique while in case 1) I can construct a sequence with two limits $0$ and $0'$. Correct?

Comment: @evilcman: All of the topological statements are correct. Not being any kind of physicist, I don’t know whether *branching* has a well-defined meaning in this context, or whether it’s simply being used to give an intuitive sense of what the problem is, but yes, either way I strongly suspect that the point is indeed that we want unique limits of convergent sequences. (By the way, if you want to be sure that I see a comment, use `@brian`. It was sheer luck that I checked back here.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I thought *manifold* meant *every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some fixed $n$*.  Is that a special case?  Can you link some sources on manifolds that allow "branching"?  Such objects arise in my work.

Comment: @avs: Every point of that space *does* have a nbhd homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. It’s just that the nbhds of $0$ and $0'$ intersect in the negative axis (or an open segment of it).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, is the intersection of those two neighborhoods a neighborhood itself?  Since that intersection contains $0 = 0'$ as a boundary point, it doesn't appear closed.

Comment: @avs: No, it’s not closed. It’s an open interval or half-line.